# Rename a file with the name of another file, maintaining the extension [SHELL]

Tags: shell

The title is self-explanatory, I want to know how I can rename a file with the name of another file maintaining the original extension, in shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming bash, you do it this way

```
file1="first file.txt"
file2="second file.html"

mv "$file1" "${file2%.*}.${file1##*.}"
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the name of the two files ahead

Comment: @Francesco: That shouldn't matter. You have to be able to put the names into variables somehow, right? Or, how are you getting the names?

Comment: I use something like this "*.avi". Can this fit into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script written in bash:

```
name="${2%.*}"
ext="${1##*.}"
filename="$name.$ext"
mv "$1" "$filename"
```

Run it with the first argument as the file you want to rename and the second argument as the filename with the name you would like to use. E.g.

```
./script foobar.txt foo.bar
```

would rename the file foobar.txt to foo.txt

Comment: This will fail on file names with spaces. Quote your variable expansions.